# Meaning of "delight the heart of a wheelbarrow"

Tags: expressions, meaning-in-context, literature

I found this sentence in The Green Fool by Patrick Kavanagh:

> I heard phrases of whimsical prophecy and exciting twists of language that would delight the heart of a wheelbarrow or a modernist poet

I'm not sure what this means. Why *delighting the heart of a wheelbarrow*?

Comment: There is a poem "The Red Wheelbarrow" by William Carlos Williams, who was a modernist poet.  That's the starting point.  Someone else will have to explain further and I look forward to a good explanation.

Comment: Yes, that could be a possible answer...it is possible that Kavanagh had read "The Red Wheelbarrow" as it was published long before The Green Fool, and he was a joker...thank you!

Comment: Also note that a wheelbarrow is hollow and has no heart.

Comment: I like the poetic explanation and it sounds wonderfully humorous and right. However the parallel implication (which I'm sure was intended) is that although a wheelbarrow is a prosaic, inanimate, object with no imagination the phrases and twists of language were so wonderful that they would affect even the wheelbarrow (or the Modernist poet). It's a bit like saying that a politician's speech at a street corner was so powerful that it stirred the very paving slabs.

Answer (score 4):

To offer a more prosaic answer :-), *heart of a wheelbarrow* is basically a slang or colourful way of saying *hard-hearted* or *humourless*. It's quite a common phrase in Ireland - Kavanagh didn't invent it. I don't know if it's common elsewhere, and Google is uncooperative in providing supporting evidence. As @HotLicks has pointed out, it stems from the fact that a wheelbarrow is hollow and has no heart.

What Kavanagh means by *delight the heart of a wheelbarrow* in this context is something like:

> extract a smile from a hard-hearted or humourless person

A more common variant is *break the heart of a wheelbarrow,* which can sometimes mean *causes extreme sadness* but more often means *causes extreme frustration.*  For example:

> trying to get around the city during rush-hour traffic would break the heart of a wheelbarrow

Answer (score 0):

The heart of a wheelbarrow is service. Mechanical objects can be viewed in this way poetically as well as usefully in writing. As a poet I sometimes eject phrases that hold no soil, but hand me the soil like a loyal friend. This is like one of them. The wheel-barrow, though, faithful companion of the gardener so fond of anthropomorphizing his pet bonsai or prize shallots views his or her tools as natural extensions of self. Creeping thoughts Through mind and body extend to his tools and self-image as a friend of horticulture.
Delighting the heart of a wheel barrow would simply be something like sunshine and fair weather in a days work instead of mud and rain in the life of a drudge. Imagine I let slip 'to warm the heart of a carburettor' I need no explanation. I , as he is simply a poet and man, master of all he surveys yet strangely connected to its ebb and flow and picking choice bon mots for our mutual delight. To delight the heart of a wheel barrow implies history of a 'life' of labour in service of his master or mankind as a whole. Clean hands delighting those temperamental keyboards. I could go on. I hope you don't think i'm trolling but there is little space for clear cut when it comes to matters of a poetic and transitional nature.